# LINQ Select from sub-list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I make a Linq query to grab ALL Productpricediscounts from a category?

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public List<Product> categoryProducts;
}

public class Product
{
    public List<Productprice> productPrices;
}

public class Productprice
{
    public List<Productpricediscount> priceDiscounts;
}
```

My query has to look something like:

```
categoryProducts.Select(p => p.productPrices).Select(x => x.?!?!
```

The problem is that I would have expected the x. - intellisense to suggest `priceDiscounts`, but I get "list"-values (like: "Any", "Select", "Distinct" and so on.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll need to use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) in order to access `priceDiscounts`:

```
var query = categoryProducts
            .SelectMany(x => x.productPrices)
            .SelectMany(y => y.priceDiscounts);
```

Comment: I think you'll need a second SelectMany instead of a Select, in order to flatten the results.

Comment: @Winston: You're right. That's actually what I wrote originally but then I edited and changed to a `Select`. I've just changed back to `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 4):

You need [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
var result = categoryProducts.SelectMany(x => x.productPrices)
             .SelectMany(x => x.priceDiscounts);
```