# Querying 2 Sets of Complex-Objects Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have two lists comprised of different complex-objects, and each one is from 2 separate data-sources. One list may-or-may-not contain records.  When any records exist in the "optional" list I need the "normal" list to be further-filtered.

Unfortunately, I can only find very simple examples [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679933/linq-select-from-sub-list) and online, which is why I am asking this question.

**The Pseudo-Logic Goes Like This:**
When `QuickFindMaterial` records exist, get all `DataSource` records where `query.Name` is in the `QuickFindMaterial.Material` collection.  If no `QuickFindMaterial` records exist do not affect the final result.  Lastly, select all distinct `DataSource`records.

**The Classes Looks Like:**

```
public class QuickFindMaterial
{
    public string SiteId { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
}
```

**The Code Looks Like:**
I have commented-out my failed `WHERE` logic below

```
    var dataSource = DocumentCollectionService.ListQuickFind();
    var quickFindMaterial = ListMaterialBySiteID(customerSiteId);

    var distinct = (from query in dataSource
                                    select new
                                               {
                                                   ID = query.DocumentID,
                                                   Library = query.DocumentLibrary,
                                                   ModifiedDate = query.DocumentModifiedDate,
                                                   Name = query.DocumentName,
                                                   Title = query.DocumentTitle,
                                                   Type = query.DocumentType,
                                                   Url = query.DocumentUrl,
                                               })
//.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(quickFindMaterial.SelectMany(q => q.Material)))
//.Where(x => quickFindMaterial.Contains(x.Name))
.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
.Where(x => !quickFindMaterial.Any() || quickFindMaterial.Any(y => x.Name == y.Material))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join on Name -> Material

Example:

```
   var distinct = (from query in dataSource
                        join foo in quickFindMaterial on query.Name equals foo.Material
                        select new
                                    {
                                        ID = query.DocumentID,
                                        Library = query.DocumentLibrary,
                                        ModifiedDate = query.DocumentModifiedDate,
                                        Name = query.DocumentName,
                                        Title = query.DocumentTitle,
                                        Type = query.DocumentType,
                                        Url = query.DocumentUrl,
                                    }).Distinct();
```