# get an item of a list in a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to get the item "numCompte" of the list "comptes" which is included in the list "clients" (which is list of a list "fc",too
Here is the code :

```
Console.WriteLine("Nom Client : {0}\n Compte : {1}\n",
       f.Clients.Select(y => y.NomClient), 
       f.Clients.Select(x => x.ComptesClient.Select(z => z.NumCompte)));
```

But, it shows me this exception:

> Value cannot be null

these are the classes :

```
public class FC
    {
        //Déclarant
        public string IdFC { get; set; }
        public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    }

public class Client
    {
        // Personne Physique
        public string IdClient { get; set; }
        public string NomClient { get; set; }
        public List<Compte> ComptesClient { get; set; }
    }

public class Compte 
    {
        public string NumCompte { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you more clearly show us what your lists contain?

Comment: I have a list "FC" that contains idFC, nameFC and clients ( which is a list<Client>) . The Client class contains idClient and comptes (which ic a list<Compte>). The compte contains numCompte

Comment: Are you trying to do this?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1680012/2258

Comment: @user1503496 is there some reason for tagging question with `xml` tag?

Comment: yes this is what i am trying to do, but it doesn't work , always the same exception
Console.WriteLine("ID CTAF : {0} \n Nom Client : {1}\n Compte : \n", f.IdFichierCtaf, f.Clients.SelectMany(y => y.NomClient ));

Comment: oh sorry Sergey , there is no raison

Comment: @user1503496 OK, then I have another question - both queries return sequence of items, but it looks like you need single item to be written to console. Can you explain what value of `NumComplete` you want to select? Or you want just count of items?

Comment: I want to display something like this : 
FC: ----
   Client : ID : ------
            Name : ----
            Compte : NumCompte : ------
            Compte / NumCompte : --------
                     
   Client :

Comment: the numCompte is the account Id of a customer. A customer may have many accounts. All customers are stored in a list FC, is that ok?

Comment: @user1503496 that's confusing - you have `"Nom Client : {0}\n Compte : {1}\n"` format string which supposed to accept two values. It would be better if you'd updated question with some sample data and expected result for that data

Comment: I think This is clear like that , I edited it

Comment: @user1503496 good, now it's clear what data structure you have. Can you now specify in English sentence what you are trying to get? E.g. *I want to get list of client ids where at least one ComptesClient exists*

Comment: Ok, I want to get the list clients(idClient) and their Account ids (numCompte)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your structure correctly, I believe you could do:

```
fc.SelectMany(i => i.numCompte).Sum();
```

Comment: no I want the value of the numCompte which belongs the list Compte. The list compte belongs to the list Client

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the list clients(idClient) and their Account ids
>   (numCompte)

Getting client ids (make sure your `Clients` list is not `null`):

```
f.Clients.Select(c => c.IdClient)
```

Getting account ids (make sure both `Clients` and `ComptesClient` lists are not `null`):

```
f.Clients.SelectMany(c => c.ComptesClient.Select(cc => cc.NumCompte))
```