# item in a list of a list is not beeing displayed

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq-to-xml

[image]

it shows me the idfichier, and the nomclient shows system.linq.enumerable... 
I guess it is showing the type of nomclient.

```
public static void generateCTAF(string pathXml, string outputPDF)
        {
            List<FichierCTAF> fc = new List<FichierCTAF>();

            fc = getXmlFCtaf(pathXml);

            foreach (FichierCTAF f in fc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID CTAF : {0} \n Nom Client : {1}\n \n", f.IdFichierCtaf, f.Clients.Select(y => y.NomClient ));
            }

        }
```

How can I display that? the picture displays the result that i got

Comment: Well what on earth does `getXmlFCtaf` do? What does it return? Have you checked the value of `fc`? What is it? Have you checked what `f.Clients` *actually* contains?

Comment: hhh take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305675/xml-element-not-present-and-list-null-and-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instanc

Comment: What exactly is `f.Clients`? A list? A list of lists?

Comment: @user1503496 take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287516/get-an-item-of-a-list-in-a-list Why are you keep posting and posting new questions?

Comment: F.Clients is a list of customers.
sergey because i get another error not the same

Comment: @user1503496 OK, then please provide exception details and point on code which thrown exception

Comment: There is no exception , it works and i debugged it and the data is stored correctly in the lists , but they are not displayed? the picture says what I want to say ( the value of nomClient is "castel")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see that strange `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator` because it's `ToString()` representation of list iterator, which is returned by `f.Clients.Select(y => y.NomClient)` query.

If you need to display all `NomClient` values, I suggest you to build concatenated string of them:

```
public static void generateCTAF(string pathXml, string outputPDF)
{
    List<FichierCTAF> fc = getXmlFCtaf(pathXml);

    foreach (FichierCTAF f in fc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID CTAF : {0}\n Nom Client : {1}\n\n", 
           f.IdFichierCtaf, 
           String.Join(", ", f.Clients.Select(y => y.NomClient)));
    }
}
```

Or you can enumerate `NomClients` values and print each on its own line:

```
public static void generateCTAF(string pathXml, string outputPDF)
{
    List<FichierCTAF> fc = getXmlFCtaf(pathXml);

    foreach (FichierCTAF f in fc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID CTAF : {0}", f.IdFichierCtaf);

        foreach(string nomClient in f.Clients.Select(y => y.NomClient))
            Console.WriteLine(" Nom Client : {0}", nomClient);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works very well, thank you Sergey very much

Comment: I got another error , can you help me?

Comment: @user1503496 if you cannot handle with that error, then you can post code which you have problem with, if you are parsing xml, than it would be nice to see exact sample of xml which gives you error, and full description of error - message, stacktrace. But I suggest you to create new question for that

Comment: I had already edited my question , look at the code at the top , exactly the third foreach statement, it tells me that it can not convert "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>" to "String"

Comment: @user1503496 please, do not modify question. You can add more details to your question, but you should not change what is asked

Comment: ok , sorry. Here is the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311867/item-in-a-list-of-a-list-of-a-list-is-not-beeing-displayed-in-the-console

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `SelectMany` use `Select`

```
f.Clients.Select(y => y.NomClient)
```

**Update**: I got your problem. If you use `Select` then it returns `IEnumerable<String>` so you need iterate to print the values of `NomClient`.

Currently you are not looping to print multiple values, below is the example to print values in comma separated.

```
String.Join(", ", f.Clients.Select(y => y.NomClient))
```

Use below line:

```
Console.WriteLine("ID CTAF : {0} \n Nom Client : {1}\n \n", f.IdFichierCtaf, String.Join(", ", f.Clients.Select(y => y.NomClient)));
```

Comment: i did but it doesn't work